# Uploading image to trello using API

Tags: c#, trello

In trello api documentation we have this POST method to upload a file into a card but using curl.

curl -v -F token={TrelloToken} -F file=@test.pdf https://api.trello.com/1/cards/5bbce18fa4a337483b145a57/attachments\?key\={APIKey}\&token\={TrelloToken}

As I am using C#, I did build this method to try to upload an image but it turns out that the file upload (or not) but it seems that the extention of the file is not the correct one. I actually don't know if it is the file that I request to upload or not, because I am not able to open when I download it. The attached image shown the result of a test that I made. In this [link](https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsidattachments-1) have the documentation and I don't know where I am stuck.

```
public static string CreateCard(string title, string description, string listId, string imagePath, string key, string token)
    {
        string id = string.Empty;
        string url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards";
        Cards card = new Cards();
        card.name = title;
        card.desc = description;
        card.idList = listId;
        card.pos = "bottom";
        card.key = key;
        card.token = token;
        card.keepFromSource = "all";
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card);
        string serverResponse =   GenericPost(url, jsonData, token, key);
        var objId = JObject.Parse(serverResponse)["id"];
        id = objId.ToString();
        UploadAttachment(key, token, id, imagePath,title);
        return id;
    }
  public static void UploadAttachment(string key, string token, string cardId, string imagePath,string name)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(imagePath);
        string url = $"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{cardId}/attachments";
        Attachments at = new Attachments();
        at.token = token;
        at.key = key;
        at.id = cardId;
        at.file = imagePath;
        at.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        at.name = name;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(at);
       string respo=  GenericPostImage(url,json,token,key);

    }


public static string GenericPostImage(string url, string JSONpostData, string token, string key)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            string header = $"key={key}&token={token}";
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, header);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            using (StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                wtr.Write(JSONpostData);
                wtr.Close();
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
            return strResponseValue;
        }
```

[image: THIS IS THE RESULT OF THE TEST]

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What exactly does not work as expected and what do you expect that should happen?

Comment: What I want to know is why the file is not uploading properly?

Comment: The file there it is not an image like should be and if was an image, Trello supposed to show a preview when I get in the card.When I download this file, there is no extension for it.